# How to maintain last screen data in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-redux

current selected place

[image]

How to do situation like this in react native ?

When I select next place it will show current place map , and when I press back it should show last seen map of that place.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use redux and store the data like a stack. And on back button press pop out the last object from the stack.